# How to play a AES-128 encrypted HLS video by javafx?

Tags: video, encryption, javafx, http-live-streaming

I put two videos on the server, one is normal HLS video, the other is AES-encrypted HLS video.Then I use javafx to create a player to play them. The former video is played normally, but when I changed the url to the latter one, it shows nothing. I test the AES-encrypted video on chrome browser with a javascript plugin, it plays normally. I want to know whether javafx can play an AES-encrypted video or not. Or there is something wrong with my code.

```
package com.test.media;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MediaPlayer1 extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // the url points to an AES-encrypted video on local server
        Media media = new Media("http://localhost:8080/hlss/output.m3u8");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        player.setAutoPlay(true);
        MediaView view = new MediaView(player);

        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(view);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 800, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and one more question, I also tried to use to webpage in webview of javafx to play it, however, both of the videos could not play. And I found two different answers on the web. Now I'm not sure whether javafx support this.

Comment: When I run the code, it does nothing, and there is nothing wrong to show in the console. I'm confused what's wrong with it? Is there errors in the code?

Comment: Probably not supported. The docs only mention a basic profile: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks! Then I solved it by using the vlcj project on the github(^--^)